# CCk fields to be grouped with add another item

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I created a new content type in Drupal 6 and added fields using CCK fields like country, state and zip code. I created a group named address so that it looks like:

Address
--- Country
--- State
--- Zip

Now I want a add new item below the label "Address" so that another address can be added. Please help me. Is there any module to do this?.. It should also have remove option

EG:

Address

```
Country
State
Zip
```

Address

```
Country
State
Zip
```

+Add another Address -Remove Address

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Thanks. I need this not only for address fields but also for education fields. So that the user may add all his education qualification using add more item

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the CCK Address or Location modules, you can accomplish this using [the 3.x branch of CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck). This branch has a module called *Multigroup*, which allows you to group fields together, and then get the *add another* functionality on the entire group.

Comment: This is the best way, I think. I've used it in several sites with the requirement of 'compound' fields.

Comment: Sorry.. But this doesnt have a remove option in it.. All it has add more values button only. Please help me

Comment: It doesn't have a button, but there should be checkboxes next to each item to delete them. You should be able to re-work this in your theme to provide the UI you want.

Answer (score 0):

There are modules that will create the fields for you and integrate with CCK. I would recommend looking at the [Location module](http://drupal.org/project/location) or the [Addresses module](http://drupal.org/project/addresses).

I have not used the Addresses module, but I know that the Location module will do exactly what you want.  You can choose which parts of the address to show and allow adding/removing extra addresses.

Comment: Thanks.  I need this not only for address fields but also for education fields. So that the user may add all his education qualification using add more item

Comment: @Ram If you are using CCK, you can allow users to add any number of values to a field by changing the __Number of values__ setting in the "Global Values" fieldset in the settings form for the CCK field.